# How to print a table of generated images in C#

Tags: c#, image, printing

I need to print a set of generated images in a table like structure with headings.  These heading and images are never displayed on the screen.  The images are generate QR codes for a series of URLS so they can easier be read in by a scanner.  There need to be a header on each column and a text id field on each row but apart from that the rows would be 4-6 columns of QR codes (2d barcode).

I have found samples for printing images and samples for printing text and even a sample to print a datagrid shown on the screen but nothing for printing text and images in a table like structure.  Could anyone help me out with a basic example.  The table is expected to go over multiple pages vertically so I would also need to put the heading row on each page.

Even pointing me in the right direction would be useful.

This is for a windows application where I want to have code kick off a print job with no user interaction. Using dotnet 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my method for creating and printing FixedDocument [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073644/wpf-auto-line-number-for-flowdocument/6146786#6146786) including source code.  This method will easily allow you to generate aligned tables with images and text and save them as XPS or print them to a printer.

Comment: You code looks good.  I have only had a quick look and i will have a more detailed look when i get home tonight nit i did not see how you add images in the table etc. Would i just create a copy of the "AddTextBlock" method but for an image instead? Also does this mean i need to calculate the table cells etc my self as exact positions for both the columns and the rows? I have never played with printing before so just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: Just to be clear it is the table structure part with heading on the top of each page that has me a little confused with your code.  IF i have read the code correctly i would need to do that myself right?  Calculate the x,y for each cell and the size as well as add a header row if it is on a new page or did i miss something when i skimmed the code and example

Comment: Got a chance to play with the code a little.Very simple and easy to use I love it.  Got table like layout working and understand that all now.  Have not tried images yet.  Just text so far.  Is there a way to put a vertical line down the page for a column?  Only way i could think of is a thin black image on each line in the same position.

Comment: You can add anything you want because the backing is a Canvas.  To make a black line just modify the routine that creates the Canvas to add a black line where you want each time a new page is created.  If you like my answer, please be sure to click the check to accept my answer.  Thanks!